# lastInsertId() with UPDATE statement returns 0 when using php7.2

Tags: pdo, mariadb, php-7.2

I have the following code to update a row in a MariaDB table:

```
<?php
$statement = <<<SQL
UPDATE `my_table`
SET
    `my_name` = :my_name,
    `my_id`   = LAST_INSERT_ID(my_id)
WHERE `my_id` = :my_id;
SQL;

try {
   $sth = $this->dbh->prepare($statement);
   $sth->bindValue(':my_name', 'Foo');
   $sth->bindValue(':my_id', 12, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $sth->execute();
   if ($this->dbh->lastInsertId() == 0) {
       echo 'Id not found!';
   }
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
   echo 'Transaction failed!';
}
```

The `my_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(my_id)` part in my SET clause, sets the value of Maria DB's `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to the value of `my_id` of the updated row.

Executing `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` in my sql client confirms the value is set (result = 12).

In php I use `PDO::lastInsertId` to get this value and if it's 0, a matching row doesn't exist. This way I can make a difference between a 'my_id doesn't exist' error and a silent UPDATE of nothing (and all other transaction errors).

This works fine in PHP **5.6.23**/MariaDB **10.1.13**, but now I'm at PHP **7.2.11**/MariaDB **10.1.36** and the returnvalue of `PDO::lastInsertId` remains zero while the row is updated indeed.

Did the behavior of `PDO::lastInsertId` change between this versions?
Is it some kind of bug?
Did the code work accidentally before, but it contains an error or something?

Thank you for your response.

---

Edit: I can confirm the code still works with PHP v7.1.8

Comment: Why not using `PDOStatement::rowCount()` to get the affected rows?

Comment: @Dormilich Because `PDOStatement::rowCount()` returns 0 when the row data didn't effectively change. (Update data is the same al the already stored data.)

Comment: Is it important to know if the update produced a match? I'd assume it makes sense for a read operation, but for an update I don't see the necessity.

Comment: Lets assume a user wants to edit an asset, but while editing, another user deletes this asset from the dB. `PDO::execute` will silently execute the statement (and `PDO::rowCount` will be 0), even if the id isn't present anymore in the dB. If the asset doesn't exist anymore, I want to report it to the user to avoid him being surprised his changes didn't apply and the asset seems to be lost instead. I've used multiple statements in previous versions of my code to achieve this, but converted it to a single statement later on, which worked perfectly until now.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
   , `my_id`   = LAST_INSERT_ID(my_id)
```

There is no need for it; the `WHERE` clause is already verifying that it is set.

I can't say whether something changed; but I really think you should change your code.

Comment: That is the necessary part to set the value of LAST_INSERT_ID, not to set the id. As per manual: `If one gives an argument to LAST_INSERT_ID(), then it will return the value of the expression and the next call to LAST_INSERT_ID() will return the same value.`

Comment: @dnFer - But it would be getting the id from some _previous_ statement, I think.

Comment: Nope... it returns the value as set as the expression. I think a following  INSERT statement will return a new value if the row contains an auto generated value, but you can't execute two statements at once anyhow.

Comment: @dnFer - Please describe, in words, the purpose of the `UPDATE`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53477085/lastinsertid-with-update-statement-returns-0-when-using-php7-2#comment93863646_53477085

Comment: @dnFer - Ah, you need "transactions" or test for non-existence, or something else.

Comment: Test for non existence it is... I can do do it by altering my code, but the behaviour of PDO has changed. That's what the question is about. However... any smart code is always welcome.

Comment: @dnFer - Instead, check `rows_affected` after doing the `UPDATE`.  "0" would say that the row does not exist.

Comment: That doesn't exist for PDO. Instead it's PDO::rowCount which doesn't count unchanged rows by default.